# Using dynamic input shape in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am working with some data that contains some features in some continues days and the shape of the array of each of these data is as below:

`(number of days, 1, number of features)`

Number of features in each of these data is different.

I want to feed each of these data, separately to my lstm model. So I want to implement my model in a way that its input shape is dynamic.

I have used this code:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1, None)))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile (
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
)
```

That `None` in the first layer is for number of features. But I get this error for this layer when I start to fit the model on (X_train and y_train):

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

I am using tensorflow version '2.3.0-tf'

Can you help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

The Function, `pad_sequences` will be useful in this case.

For example, `Input Sequences` has different number of `Features` as shown below:

```
sequences = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
             [1]
    ]
```

We can make all the `Features` of equal length using `pad_sequences`, as shown below:

```
padded = pad_sequences(sequences)
```

That will make `Input Sequence`:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

That is, it will pad the other `Features` with `Zeros` and will make the Number of `Features` of all the Samples as 4 (Maximum among them).

The `Padding` with `Zeros` can be done at the `start` or at the `end` by adjusting the argument, 'padding'. For more details about this Function, please refer this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences).

Complete working code with variable number of Features is shown below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# define sequences
sequences = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
             [1]
    ]

# pad sequence
padded = pad_sequences(sequences)
print(padded)
X = np.expand_dims(padded, axis = 0)
print(X.shape) # (1, 3, 4)

y = np.array([1,0,1])
y = y.reshape(1,-1)
print(y.shape) # (1, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile (
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

model.fit(x = X, y = y)
```

Output of above code is :

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 0 0 1]]

(1, 3, 4)

(1, 3)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2601
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I had a question. When we pad the array with zeros, won't this zeros affect the result of the model?

Comment: In such case, you can use `Masking`. Refer the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding#masking for more details.